# Cant create a relation in mysql - Error creating foreign key on id_produk (check data types)

Tags: mysql, sql

here is my table :

```
CREATE TABLE `pesanan` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ref_number` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `id_produk` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `qty` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `total` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `tanggal` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

i want to create a relation of id_produk to table produk.id and id_user to user.id, here is the other table :

```
CREATE TABLE `produk` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_kategori` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `slug` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `judul` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `harga` varchar(10) DEFAULT '',
  `target` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `desc` text,
  `cover` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tanggal` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=29 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and user table

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `suspended` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `level` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nama` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `alamat` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=23 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

when i try to relation it , it give me this error :

**Error creating foreign key on id_produk (check data types)**

Comment: What did you try? ...and both should be unsigned or signed, that can't differ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The columns should have the exact same data type in both tables. In your case in the "produk" and "user" tables they are unsigned, which means they go from 0 to 4294967295 but in the "pesanan" table they are signed which means they go from -2147483648 to 2147483647. See more [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html).

If the server allowed you to create such foreign keys, it would possibly create situations where, for example, a user is added with and ID of 2147483648 that cannot ever be referenced in the "pesanan" table.

You should change the "id_produk" and "id_user" columns in the "pesanan" table to be unsigned.

Comment: it Works . Thanks so much !